# JavaFX2 client and a Server

Tags: java, client-server

I am planning on writing an application for a hospital. I am planning to use Javafx to build user interfaces. I want help in choosing the way I write the server and client communication.
I want the client(which knows the server's address) to call the server functionality just like it would call in a standalone application.
How do I achieve this?
Note: I don't want to write a web based application

Comment: For a simple complete example, I recommend reviewing the zenjava article [Client Server with JavaFX 2 and Hessian (+Guice +FXML)](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/03/client-server-with-javafx-2-and-hessian-guice-fxml/) for a possible implementation which may fit your needs.  The question is a too open-ended to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Web services (SOAP, REST) or RMI calls are all for you.

Comment: I thought web-services are run on a web-server?

Comment: Web services run on an application server. Which could be also a web server.

Comment: i know of axis2, but can it return a java object? can i pass a java object?

Comment: @AlwinDoss, look at axis2 wsdl2java